# missing slash in os.path.join result from tkinter filedialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4, python-os

What's wrong with the way I'm joining my path here?

Everything but the first item in the list will be properly joined.

I'm grabbing a path from a filedialog in tkinter.

i.e filedialog.askdirectory()

Example Path:

```
PATH = "C:/MyUserName/Desktop/SomeDir"
```

What I'm doing:

```
os.path.join(*(PATH.split("/") + ["somefile.txt"]))
```

This will print out the following:

```
C:MyUserName/Desktop/SomeDir/somefile.txt
```

Why does it lose the first `/`?

Comment: can't reproduce. Works for me in 2.7

Comment: cannot reproduce to.

Comment: @Slayer could you provide more code ?

Comment: You don't need to use `split` before you call `join`. The first argument to `join` can just be `PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to convert my initial path using `os.normpath` I was getting a filedialog input from tkinter and then trying to use the above path style / code in the question to access / create files.

Because of the bad join / seperators on windows it was causing errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Windows, right?

From the Docs:

> On Windows, the drive letter is not reset when an absolute path component (e.g., r'\foo') is encountered. If a component contains a drive letter, all previous components are thrown away and the drive letter is reset. Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

This means that c:foo is in fact a correct path. Try `os.path.abspath('c:foo')` and `os.path.abspath('c:\\foo')` to see the difference. The first path is a relative path on the c drive and the second one is an absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

Windows keeps a current path for all drives. `C:MyUserName/Desktop/SomeDir/somefile.txt` and `C:/MyUserName/Desktop/SomeDir/somefile.txt` are both valid and there is no way for `ntpath.join` to know whether you wanted the drive-relative or drive-absolute path.