# pathlib.Path('C:').absolute().is_absolute() returns False

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib, os.path

**Issue:**

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('C:').absolute().is_absolute()   # Is 'C:' absolute if we try to make it with pathlib?
False

>>> os.path.isabs(os.path.abspath('C:'))  # Is 'C:' absolute if we try to make it with os.path?
True

>>> os.path.isabs('C:')                   # Is 'C:' absolute on it's own?
False

# Correct way to get absolute path as suggested in answers below
>>> Path('C:').resolve()
WindowsPath('C:/Windows/system32')        # We get a folder we have launched Python from
```

- How comes `Path.absolute()` returns a non-absolute path?
- Who's right, who's wrong?
- Bonus quesion: Which function wraps windows' drive letter `(C:)` to path `(C:\\)`, so `os.path.join` would work properly?

**Example:**

Try to get a file path out of a 'path' and 'filename', and given the file finds itself in root of a Windows OS disk, you'll have trouble creating a path that is functional

```
>>> a_path = 'C:'
>>> a_file_name = 'foo.txt'

>>> os.path.join(a_path, a_file_name)
'C:foo.txt'

>>> os.path.isabs(os.path.abspath('C:'))
True
```

and to add a pinch of confusion, if you create the file at C:\foo.txt prior; you'll get:

```
>>> os.path.exists('C:foo.txt')
False
>>> os.path.exists(os.path.abspath('C:foo.txt'))
False
```

Alternative execution with the pathlib

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('C:').joinpath('foo.txt')
WindowsPath('C:too.txt')
>>> Path('C:').joinpath('foo.txt').is_absolute()
False
```

**Real life situation:**

Apparently, Cinema4D's Python SDK method `doc.GetDocumentPath()` returns in fact `C:` if the document in question is located in the root folder on the C: drive.

**Related quesions:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35909115/4566456
- [How to get absolute path of a pathlib.Path object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513056/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-a-pathlib-path-object)

Comment: I would report this as a bug, but ultimately, the problem is simply that Windows is crazy.

Answer (score 3):

The `absolute()` method isn't actually part of the `pathlib.Path` documented public API. It doesn't really work, and you're not supposed to use it. It's got comments in its [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/pathlib.py#L1050) saying stuff like "XXX untested yet!" and "FIXME".

The actual, documented method for getting an absolute path is [`Path.resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve). I think that one *should* behave correctly for this input... but I think "behave correctly" means returning an absolute path to your current working directory on the C drive. I don't think it's going to return `'C:\\'`. Also, unlike `os.path.abspath`, `Path.resolve` requires a path that actually resolves to something, and it'll also resolve symbolic links.

If you want something that behaves like `os.path.abspath`, use `os.path.abspath`. Pathlib does not support a direct equivalent of that function.

Comment: Amazing! Still looking for a sane solution to the realworld problem...

Comment: @DayDreamer: I think the solution to your real-world problem is probably just to special-case this. If Cinema4D hands you a path that's just a drive letter and a colon, add a backslash yourself.